# Web Deploy Automatic Backups not creating backup

Tags: visual-studio, webserver, backup, publish, iis-10

I tried to set up Automatic Backups on a server running websites on IIS version 10.

On IIS, I have set the backups on site level with Configuration Editor:

[image]

As well as on global level by editing the applicationHost.config file as per below:

[image]

On VS 2022, I have a publish profile, with the below configuration:
[image]

Based on this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-web-deploy/web-deploy-automatic-backups I expect this to work. Yet, I can publish successfully, but no backups are created when I Publish from VS. I at least expect the publish to fail, because no backups are made, based on the setting: continueSyncOnBackupFailure=False

Comment: Please make sure give read access to the IIS_IUSRS group on the backup folder.

Answer (score 0):

<s>I've checked my settings, looks pretty much the same on my side. EXCEPT the path and that I backup a specific site, not global. I did `D:\backup\`, chance as per your env. But I assume you've solved it by now.</s>

---

So, coincident or not, just today I've had to setup a VM and site for which I could not even publish from MSVS. I'm gonna go through all I did, hopefully you can try and pick something that works for you.

**Publishing from MSVS fix:**

1. in configuration manager, the backup section was missing. So I fiddled with the `applicationHost.config` file over from `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config`. I manually added the sections, by searching the keyword `backup` from an already correctly populated file from my working env. Make sure you backup `applicationHost.config` this before making mods.

[image]

2. after adding the sections, I made mods as per my liking in the configuration manager in IIS manager. Enabling the backup feature, setting path etc
3. next I found out that I had missing the Management Service role from Server manager, so install that.

[image]

4. After installing that, open services and start/restart both of these services. Put them on automatic too.

[image]

5. Close and reopen IIS manager too

---

This should have fixed my publishing

---

**No backup fix:**

1. Next go ahead and [download](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy) the Web Deploy installer. Make sure you pick correct OS architecture. Download links should bet at the bottom
2. Uninstall it if you have it installed already
3. Do complete install
4. Do iisrest
5. Go to your site, right click, you MUST see the deploy section

[image]

6. Click on configure. Modify according to your needs
7. Click setup
8. In the results settings you should see messages confirming the location of your settings files and some other success messages etc
9. Re-check your backup settings in configuration manager, because I had the surprise to discover they were placed back to the default. So re-edit those if it's the case. Make sure you write some path and not leave the defaults, yes?

---

I think that's all I did, if I omitted anything maybe I'll edit and post a comment to let you know.

Comment: No, this has not been resolved. I've changed my settings to use a hard-coded absolute path like you mentioned, but when I publish the backups are still not happening.

Comment: Hang, on, today I had to do settings for a new VM, new site which kind of replicated your issue. I'm trying to compose all the steps I took maybe you can fix it on your side. @Divan

Comment: Backups are still not appearing after following those steps. Are there logs where one could see any potential errors in creating the backups? As my publishes are successful, the backups are just not happening as configured.

Comment: Do you see deploy section as on the step 5 screen clip? Try to use local account placed in admin group for there. Did you restart both services? Did you restart IIS? Did you make sure the folder setting in configuration manager is custom and not default? I'm sorry for insinuating that you didn't even if you maybe did all of these things.

Comment: Try an do what Samwu said on his comment. For example my publish account used is in the admin group, also on step 5, on the deploy, I use the same account. So it has automatic access on my custom backup folder. Make sure to check the security tab on that folder.